# Create android custom selector view

Tags: android, view, android-custom-view

I am developing Meeting Room Booking Application which show the list of available rooms on particular day. Now i need to show time slots in which that particular room is available, so that user can select appropriate time slot and book the room for meeting, for this i need to create this below type view for showing time slot. This screenshot is taken from an application, i know it is not a readymade android view and i have to create custom view for this. But does anyone has created this kind of view or anyone has some link of any tutorial that has this type of view. As i have strict deadlines, any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I would suggest to use https://github.com/AyeMyaThu/waveform-android. If you want to customize more then do let me know.

Comment: @AnuragSingh: Your library contains dual horizontal scroll bar as in above image?

Comment: @AnuragSingh : Value selector as in above image